# How to get git flow completions for zsh working?

Tags: git, zsh

I have `git` and `git-flow` installed via Homebrew. I am on a Mac.

I have `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0)`

`git` completions are working. `git-flow` completions are not.

I cannot get `git flow` completions to work.

I've tried two ways to install the functions.

**Method 1**

I installed `git-flow` using Homebrew, which added the functions to this directory `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`

That path is in my `$fpath`

```
> echo $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/share/zsh/functions
```

**Method 2**

I downloaded the `git-flow` completion functions from [https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_git-flow) and put the file in `~/.zsh/completions`.

I then added the directory to my `~/.zshrc`

```
fpath=(~/.zsh/completions $fpath)

> echo $fpath
/Users/jord/.zsh/completions /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/share/zsh/functions
```

Neither of these methods works.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The output of `git-flow [CTRL+X] [h]` is:

```
> git flow
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    all-files  (_files _default _git (eval))
```

**UPDATE 2**

It's working!

I put the `_git` functions from the [URL provided by @mpy](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_git) in `~/.zsh/completions/` and added `~/.zsh/completions` to my `$fpath` in `~/.zshrc`.

```
fpath=(
  ~/.zsh/completions
  $fpath
)
```

I then downloaded `git-flow-completion.zsh` from https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion and put it into `~/.zsh/completions` and sourced that file from my `.zshrc`.

`git` and `git flow` completions are now working, but I have no idea why?!

Comment: Both methods should be fine. As it is working here and just to make sure: Did you start a new zsh instance after putting the file into `$fpath`? And, can you please post the output of `git-flow [CTRL+X] [h]`?

Comment: I've updated my post with the output. I assume this means it can't find the `git-flow` completions, only the `git` completions?

Comment: I wrote an answer, although I don't have a solution. But perhaps one of my ideas for troubleshooting will help -- and I couldn't fit everything into a comment ';)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `$fpath/_git-flow` provides completion for `git-flow` (with dash), see its first line:

```
#compdef git-flow
```

So, using `git-flow [CTRL+X] [h]` I get

```
$ git-flow [CTRL+X] [h]
tags in context :completion::complete:git-flow::
    argument-1  (_arguments _git-flow)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-flow:argument-1:
    commands  (_describe _git-flow)
```

showing that `zsh` detects that the prompt is now at the first argument to `git-flow`.

The completion function for `git` is *very* powerful (and to be honest, I cannot ,,read'' it through), so also `git flow` (w/o dash) provides the `git-flow` completion, but the context is different:

```
$ git flow [CTRL+X] [h]
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-rest  (_arguments _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-flow::
    argument-1  (_arguments _git-flow _call_function _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-flow:argument-1:
    commands  (_describe _git-flow _call_function _git)
```

If using a non existent git module, I end up with

```
$ git foo [CTRL+X] [h]
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-rest  (_arguments _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git-foo::
    directories    (_files _git) 
    globbed-files  (_files _git) 
    all-files      (_files _git)
```

which looks closest to your result.

Therefore my suggestions would be:

- check your `_git-flow` completions file isn't corrupted and *has the right line endings (EOL)*
- trigger completion for git-flow with e.g. `git-flow [CTRL+X] [h]` and have a look at the output of `which _git-flow`:

  - if the completion function cannot be read this results in

    ```
    $ which _git-flow
    _git-flow () {
            # undefined
            builtin autoload -XUz
    }
    ```
  - if read correctly you get the function printed:

    ```
    $ which _git-flow
    _git-flow () {
        local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
        typeset -A opt_args
        _arguments -C ':command:->command' '*::options:->options'
        ...
    ```
- try to compile the `_git-flow` function file with `zcompile _git-flow` to see if there will be an error. (Then the resulting file `_git-flow.zwc` should be read upon autoloading.)
- examine `~/.zcompdump` if the `_git-flow` completion is listed.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. If I compile the function file with `zcompile` the completions show up, but only for `git-flow` not `git flow`. Why is it necessary to compile the functions? And how can I get it working for `git flow`?

Comment: @jordelver: Frankly, I don't know, why it's working when compiled. That _shouldn't_ matter. Do you have the up-to-date version of the `_git` completion? If there is a older version of `_git` somewhere in your `$fpath` things might get screwed up. Try to compile `_git` as well?!

Comment: If I have two versions of the functions which take precedence? I have a `_git` file in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` AND in `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.2/share/zsh/functions`. Once is the default zsh install, one is installed by the git Homebrew package :|

And, they are different, one seems to be zsh script only and the other uses the bash completions :/

Comment: @jordelver: I don't know what happens with two identical named files, but it sounds like a source of irritations. Try to move both files out of `$fpath` and put only the _official_ `_git` function from http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Completion/Unix/Command/_git into `$fpath`.

Comment: Ok, it's working! But I don't have any idea why ;) See my update at the top. I don't understand why I have `source` files when there seems to be an `_` convention, but anyway, it's working. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @jordelver You have to source `git-flow-completion.zsh` precisely because that author decided not to follow the `_` convention. It still works the same, but you have to source it instead of dropping it in an `fpath` location to let Zsh pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I thought you could try this:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/f710a1395f44224e4bcc3518ee9c13a0dc850be1#r30789420

You are running macOS ?
The autocompletions come with Homebrew git were conflict with the git-flow autocompletions script.

Try to remove the zsh folder in `/usr/local/Cellar/git/x.xx.x/share/` and reload your zsh.

References:
1. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/f710a1395f44224e4bcc3518ee9c13a0dc850be1
2. https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/issues/50
3. https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1717